# JAXB: Is it possible to handle unknown elements

Tags: java, tags, jaxb

i get xml content like this:

```
<data>
   <randomtagname>
      <name>....</name>
      <description>.....</description>
      <description>.....</description>
   </randomtagname>
   <anotherrandomtagname>
      <name>....</name>
      <description>.....</description>
   </anotherrandomtagname>
   <thirdridiculousrandomtagname>
      <name>....</name>
      <description>.....</description>
      <description>.....</description>
   </thirdridiculousrandomtagname>
       .
       .
       .
</data>
```

is it possibe to create an annotated java class and use jaxb to un-/marshall this file without using @XmlAnyElement??

Comment: is your source xml so undefined that you could extract an XSD? If you can extract xsd, you can build classes java and don't need to be worried with this... and if not (not possible XSD extraction) why not apply DOM?

Comment: the random tag names can! vary each time i get and need to parse them.  so i have no idea if it would be possible to generate an xsd. but id dont want to change my code all the time the content of the xml has changed, because the inner structure of the radnom tags is still the same

Comment: @spaeth: to the dom part: i want to avoid manual dom parsing. but, it seems i have no luck this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a list of Objects to me. Make a java class that has a

```
 List<Object> data
```

variable. You should not need the annotation for that.

Basically you want your xml interface to be generic enough to accept a list of different objects which may have different fields. Once this interface accepts a list of java objects, its up to your java code to determine what they are and cast them to correct class type. Use instanceOf for that part. Some of this is described in java generics where you can pass in any Object, but you have to determine what it is to cast it. I think as long as its sent over in its real class form, instanceof will work. You wouldnt send over a list of Objects, you would send a list of things like String, Integer, or custom classes like Myclass1, Myclass2. Then once you read that list use instanceof to determine the object type of each object in the list, is it instance of String, Myclass1, Myclass2, etc... And cast appropriately.

Reading your question closer I may be missing what you really need to know. Maybe this link hasbsomething that would help. [jaxb help](http://roseindia.net/jaxb/r/jaxb.shtml)

Comment: but what is object in this case? i still dont understand how to identify the single 'objects' to cast to any other class to do sth like myObject.getName() or myObject.getDescription()[0].

Comment: Object here would be Any type of java object. You could have different objects in the list, to cast them you use instanceOf to determine what type of object it is. If obj1.instanceOf(MyClass1.class) MyClass1 objcl1 = (MyClass1) obj1;

Comment: sure, i know. so you say in this case i should do my own dom parsing? like spaeth mentioned? and dont use jaxb in this special case?

Comment: You may have to if you do not have access to the classes that the file was created with. Ive used the java sax parser for something similar. I read it was better than dom parser.

Comment: In fact it depends on your priority, SAX parser is a kind of parser that doesn't need to "know" the entire document, DOM in other hand will interpret the whole document first and present the data in a structured way (tree more precisely). Due this reason SAX is good for big documents, but is no so easy to access data as DOM.

Comment: sine i am very new to jaxb, it took a while to understand what you mentioned. thanks to both of you. List<Object> works fine for me.